# Dynamic scheduler in Liferay

Tags: cron, liferay, liferay-6, scheduler

I need to execute a task periodically in Liferay, I find that you can create a class that implements `MessageListener` and in the `receive` method you can implement the action. Until here its fine, but after this to program the time you need to do it in `liferay-portlet.xml`, if the xml file is used I cannot edit the duration dynamically.

Is there any way I can create a task that can be programmed to dynamically get the values for scheduling duration from the DB?

I believe that with `SchedulerEngineUtil` I must to be able tho do this, but I don't know if it's the correct way or how do it?

Does anyone know how I can find any documentation and some example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, to execute a task periodically you must implement MessageListener and do the following in your liferay-portlet.xml -

`<scheduler-entry>
<scheduler-event-listener-class>com.#className</scheduler-event-listener-class>
<trigger>
<simple>
<simple-trigger-value>1</simple-trigger-value>
<time-unit>minute</time-unit>
</simple>
</trigger>
</scheduler-entry>`

This will trigger the event listener class every 1 minute.So try fetching data from DB using Util method in here.
Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks, but exists any way to do this dynamically? that the user can change the time or periodicity?

Comment: Check these links - http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/20749558 and http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/11799978

Answer (score 0):

To add a dynamic scheduler you have to implement a `MessageListener` and register it using the `SchedulerEngineHelperUtil`:

```
String pId = "portlet id here";  // TODO put portlet ID here

Message msg = new Message();
msg.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, pId);
msg.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, MyListener.class.getName());

Trigger listener = new IntervalTrigger(MyListener.class.getName(), MyListener.class.getName(), 50);
SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule(
    listener, StorageType.PERSISTED, "some description",
    DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH, msg, 0);
```

You may also want to read [my answer also covering a solution for creating a static scheduled-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35194627/running-a-scheduled-task-in-liferay-6-2-ga6/35197713#35197713).

Answer (score 0):

The time is set in cronText, where 12 is minutes and 10 is hours. Currently this cronText makes it schedule every day at 10:12 am.

```
String portletId = "yourportlet_WAR_yourportlet";
String cronText = "0 12 10 1/1 * ? *";

Message message = new Message();
message.put(SchedulerEngine.MESSAGE_LISTENER_CLASS_NAME, YourListenerClass.class.getName());
message.put(SchedulerEngine.PORTLET_ID, portletId);
message.put("portletId", portletId);

SchedulerEngineHelperUtil.schedule(
    new CronTrigger("jobName", "jobGroup", cronText),
    StorageType.PERSISTED,
    "Message Scheduler Description",
    DestinationNames.SCHEDULER_DISPATCH,
    message,
    0);
```